# ADF replace special characters

Tags: replace, newline, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass the following string without single, double quotes, and new-line characters to Azure functions. I tried to replace the string in  ADF to remove the single quotes and new-line characters in the following way. It didn't work. Kindly assist me how to replace all the special characters(',",\n)

@replace(activity('CPY_ACTIVITY').output.errors[0].Message,''','')
@replace(activity('CPY_ACTIVITY').output.errors[0].Message,'\n','')

Below is the error while performing copy activity to snowflake. I am trying to pass this error to Azure functions without special characters.

ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [22007] Date 'SUNDAY' is not recognized\n  File 'sample_file.csv', line 2, character 14\n  Row 1, column sample_table[DAY_DATE:2]\n  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,'
'Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [22007] Date 'SUNDAY' is not recognized\n  File 'sample_file.csv', line 2, character 14\n  Row 1, column sample_table[DAY_DATE:2]\n  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.,
Source=Snowflake,'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace characters using **replace** function as below.

1. **Output before replacing**:

[image]

2. Use `''''` to replace single quote.

`@replace(string(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message),'''','')`

**Output after replacing single quote:**

[image]

3. Replacing `\n` along with a single quote from the error output (**press enter** in place of line breaker or **add \n in code**).

`@replace(string(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message),' ','')`

You can also include '\n' in **Json Code to replace (\n)** line breaker looks like:

```
                "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "error_code",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@replace(string(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message),'\n','')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
```

[image]

4. **Replace double quote (")**

`@replace(string(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message),'"','')`

[image]

Comment: Sure, you can open the json code and add '\n' under property value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to replace it as per your suggestion.

Comment: Glad it worked! If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: I don't have enough Previleage to accept this as an answer. Thanks much :)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I need a help with how to replace \r in ADF message. I tried replace('\r','') as well replace('\\r','') . Both are not working for me